# Wrongly get the OTP while check with twice or more device

Tags: google-authenticator

Why is Google Authenticator getting different OTPs while scanning the same QR code? I checked with two devices and got the same (correct) OTP, but from a different timezone (country) I’m getting OTP with wrong.

Answer (score 1):

These code are time based - You have to make sure the time on both your phone and server (where your are hosting the script) are synced.

To sync the Google Authenticator App:

My Google Authenticator codes aren’t working (Android) This might be because the time on your Google Authenticator app is not synced correctly.

To make sure that you have the correct time: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185834?hl=en

> Go to the main menu on the Google Authenticator app Tap More and then
> Settings. Tap Time correction for codes Tap Sync now On the next
> screen, the app will confirm that the time has been synced, and you
> should now be able to use your verification codes to sign in. The sync
> will only affect the internal time of your Google Authenticator app,
> and will not change your device’s Date & Time settings.